# How to calculate bed mates and length of time spent together

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with some patient data in Pandas that looks roughly like the following

| patient_id | room_id | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1001 | 01-01-2022 04:30:26 | 05-01-2022 10:14:01 |
| 1 | 1002 | 05-01-2022 10:14:01 | 10-01-2022 14:32:04 |
| 1 | 1003 | 10-01-2022 14:32:04 | 15-01-2022 08:24:16 |
| 1 | 1005 | 15-01-2022 08:24:16 | 22-01-2022 17:28:22 |
| 2 | 1004 | 03-01-2022 10:15:35 | 09-01-2022 17:02:11 |
| 2 | 1007 | 09-01-2022 17:02:11 | 12-01-2022 19:55:16 |
| 2 | 1003 | 12-01-2022 19:55:16 | 15-01-2022 08:24:16 |
| 2 | 1007 | 15-01-2022 08:24:16 | 22-01-2022 17:28:22 |
| 3 | 1004 | 05-01-2022 12:24:15 | 10-01-2022 18:49:17 |
| 3 | 1003 | 10-01-2022 18:49:17 | 12-01-2022 19:55:16 |
| 3 | 1007 | 12-01-2022 19:55:16 | 15-01-2022 08:24:16 |
| 4 | 1001 | 02-01-2022 06:36:41 | 16-01-2022 10:38:48 |

I am interested to calculate how many bed mates that patients have had in their respective rooms, and for how long for (in hours and days).

The data needs to be sorted by start_date to try and understand chronologically where patients started moving from and to.

So far I have tried `df.groupby('room_id').start_date.diff()`, but didn't quite get the results I expected.

How best can I approach this problem?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let's start by creating the dataframe OP mentions

```
import pandas as pd

patient_df = pd.DataFrame( { "patient_id": [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4], "room_id": [1001, 1002, 1003, 1005, 1004, 1007, 1003, 1007, 1004, 1003, 1007, 1001], "start_date": ["01-01-2022 04:30:26", "05-01-2022 10:14:01", "10-01-2022 14:32:04", "15-01-2022 08:24:16", "03-01-2022 10:15:35", "09-01-2022 17:02:11", "12-01-2022 19:55:16", "15-01-2022 08:24:16", "05-01-2022 12:24:15", "10-01-2022 18:49:17", "12-01-2022 19:55:16", "02-01-2022 06:36:41"], "end_date": ["05-01-2022 10:14:01", "10-01-2022 14:32:04", "15-01-2022 08:24:16", "22-01-2022 17:28:22", "09-01-2022 17:02:11", "12-01-2022 19:55:16", "15-01-2022 08:24:16", "22-01-2022 17:28:22", "10-01-2022 18:49:17", "12-01-2022 19:55:16", "15-01-2022 08:24:16", "16-01-2022 10:38:48"] } )
```

Now, in order to calculate how many bed mates the patients have had in their respective rooms for how long for (in hours and days), the following will do the work

```
newdf = patient_df.groupby(["patient_id", "room_id"]).agg({"start_date": "min", "end_date": "max"}).reset_index()
```

If one wants to sort the dataframe `newdf` by `start_date` starting from the earliest date, the following will do the work

```
newdf.sort_values(by=["start_date"], inplace=True)
```

This is the output of the final dataframe

```
print(newdf)

[Out]:
                             start_date             end_date
patient_id room_id                                          
1          1001     01-01-2022 04:30:26  05-01-2022 10:14:01
4          1001     02-01-2022 06:36:41  16-01-2022 10:38:48
2          1004     03-01-2022 10:15:35  09-01-2022 17:02:11
1          1002     05-01-2022 10:14:01  10-01-2022 14:32:04
3          1004     05-01-2022 12:24:15  10-01-2022 18:49:17
2          1007     09-01-2022 17:02:11  22-01-2022 17:28:22
1          1003     10-01-2022 14:32:04  15-01-2022 08:24:16
3          1003     10-01-2022 18:49:17  12-01-2022 19:55:16
2          1003     12-01-2022 19:55:16  15-01-2022 08:24:16
3          1007     12-01-2022 19:55:16  15-01-2022 08:24:16
1          1005     15-01-2022 08:24:16  22-01-2022 17:28:22
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I should have added the df for you.


Wouldn't I need to do something like an Overlap statement (in SQL) but in Pandas to try and get the overlapping times, that patients spent together?